# Msg 2714 - There is already an object named 'DIM_Currency' in the database

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create DIM table in my database named "DIM_Currency". But when I am executing the query, This message appears.

*Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 12
There is already an object named 'DIM_Currency' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.*

My query is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_Currency](
[CurrencyCode] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CurrencyKey] [int] NOT NULL,
[CurrencyAlternateKey] [nvarchar] (50) NULL,
[CurrencyName] [nvarchar] (50) NULL,
[EffectiveDate] [date] NULL,
[ExpirationDate] [date] NULL,
[CurrentFlag] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [DIM_Currency] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CurrencyCode] ASC)
)
```

I even tried to create this on different databases, by every solution I can find in both Stack overflow and Stack Exchange. Nothing worked. Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a constraint use the same name (identifier) as the table.

Constraint names also need to be unique within the schema.

Because of these rules, and for the sake of consistency and convenience, you'll often see constraints named with a code that indicates the type of constraint (PK, FK) and then the table name, and then usually the some other unique bit of information (like the key column name).  It ends up looking like this:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_Currency] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CurrencyCode] ASC)
```

Or

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_Currency_CurrencyCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CurrencyCode] ASC)
```